# Where to write "mysql> SHOW TABLES;" to check if table is empty

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a database with a table on my hosting service's website. Then I found this little code `mysql> SHOW TABLES;` to show me the exisiting table. But first off all *where* do I write this short code to get any output? Probably that's a stupid question, but I am a real newbie.

Comment: Many possible places. The `mysql console` or phpMyAdmin etc anywhere that will run a query for you

Comment: May be you should read some beginners tutorial such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/)

Comment: Do u have `ssh` access on that server?

Comment: This question shows a real absence of research.  Read The Manual.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks :)

Comment: @mickmackusa I did some research. I read for example this arcticle https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-tables.html But there it's not mentioned where to type these commands at all

Answer (score 0):

You should enter mysql console using command-line

assuming you are root :

```
mysql -u <db-username> -p
```

- mysql is the command
- -u is the user parameter and you should replace  with the user of your database (root for instance)
- -p means password

after this it will ask you to type the DB user's password

If it succeed, you will see something like this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19472
Server version: 5.5.30-cll MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

and you have the mysql prompt where you can enter all your database commands (queries)

Comment: Yup, I found it. Worked fine